# Download SVG element from page when user clicks

Tags: javascript, dom, svelte

I made a Svelte component, which generates a couple of SVG elements, based on some parameters. I want to provide a download-link or -button for each created SVG element, which saves the SVG code to a file on the user's computer.

I found the solution using blob and URL.createObjectURL suitable. It works if I create a static HTML page with a click handler like so:

```
<button onclick="download(50)">Download SVG</button>
```

However the same solution in Svelte does not trigger a download:

```
<script>
    const sizes = [20, 50, 90];
    
    function download(id) {
        const svg = document.getElementById(id);
        const blob = new Blob([svg.outerHTML], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = `File name ${id}.svg`;
        link.click();

        console.log(svg.outerHTML);
        console.log(blob);
        console.log(link);
    }
</script>


{#each sizes as s}
<p>
    <!-- this button does not work -->
    <button on:click={() => download(s)}>Download SVG</button>
    <br>
    <svg id={s} width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <ellipse cx="100" cy="100" rx={s} ry={s*0.7} fill="orange" stroke="black"/>
    </svg>
</p>
<hr/>
{/each}
```

Comment: How are you testing it?

Comment: Two things: first, `id` attributes can _technically_ start with a number, but really shouldn't, because that violates the CSS and JS rules for query selectors and variables, respectively. Second, [don't use the `onclick` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#registering_event_handlers): use `addEventListener` on the JS side instead.

Comment: @Unmitigated I tested it in the Svelte REPL (https://svelte.dev/repl). You can paste the code as is.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Are you referring to the onclick attribute in my static HTML example? If so, that is not what I want to use anyway - I want to make it work with Svelte. Is the `on:click` attribute not the way to go there? How else would I register an event handler in Svelte?

Comment: You should not query the DOM with Svelte, also IDs starting with numbers work but are invalid.

Comment: @H.B. not since HTML5 changed the rules for what is considered a valid `id` attribute. You can start an `id` with a number, or even a hyphen, and that's valid but _only_ in HTML context, and you can't use it in a query selector, nor will it auto-variable-assign on the JS side.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I guess I have been living in the past then 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot start downloads in the REPL because it uses an iframe to isolate the output.

This works as expected in a standalone Svelte application.